# Website available ofline

Tags: website, url

How can I make complete website/Url and child pages associated with Url available offline?

E.g. I want the android sdk at [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) to be available offline so that I can go through it any time even without Internet

Answer (score 2):

**Javadocs are** nothing but **simple HTML pages generated**.
So you don't need anything fancy, even a local browser is enough if you want to view it yourself.

If you want to host it, any webserver that is capable of serving static pages will do.

**Where can you download it?**
The SDK manager will have it under Documentation.

Alternatively you can grab them from URLs:
Such as:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-18_r02.zip

Replace the numbers. (same naming convention, so try docs-19_r02.zip first, then -19_r01.zip, so on.)
I'm sure there is a list somewhere, I just could not find it.

Comment: Seems logic that Google would, in their own SDK, include an offline copy of it's documentation.

Comment: I would not even call JavaDoc a real documentation. It's a great help while you code and sure it's detailed/documented, but good luck finding what you need through it. (See p4's great libs.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get a url working offline is to setup a web server locally and host the files / resources there itself.

Thus your computer will act as the web server to serve those contents.

Comment: This will only work if the web site is set up with relative links. If there are *any* absolute links then the links will break.

Comment: @ankur Do I really need server to view webpages offline on my local desktop?

Comment: @Guest You will not require in case the content is plain html. Your browser will display the html contents. Please throw some more light on your question so that I may understand it more clearly and come up with a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)? Quoting from the page:

> GNU Wget is a **free software package** for **retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP**, the most widely-used Internet protocols. It is a non-interactive commandline tool, so it may easily be called from scripts, cron jobs, terminals without X-Windows support, etc.
>
> GNU Wget has many features to make retrieving large files or mirroring entire web or FTP sites easy, including:
>
> - Can resume aborted downloads, using REST and RANGE
> - Can use filename wild cards and recursively mirror directories
> - NLS-based message files for many different languages
> - Optionally converts absolute links in downloaded documents to relative, so that downloaded documents may link to each other locally
> - Runs on most UNIX-like operating systems as well as Microsoft Windows
> - Supports HTTP proxies
> - Supports HTTP cookies
> - Supports persistent HTTP connections
> - Unattended / background operation
> - Uses local file timestamps to determine whether documents need to be re-downloaded when mirroring
> - GNU Wget is distributed under the GNU General Public License.

I've personally used it to store several sites to view oflline. It has a slight steep learning curve (due to arguments and such) but it has the ability of doing everything you want.

There is also a port of [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), if you don't have an UNIX machine.

The possible arguments I would use for your task would be something in the likes of:

```
wget -r -p -k -np -w 1 http://developer.android.com/reference/
```

Explaining the commands:

- `-r` - Sets recursive retrieval (i.e. it will get any link that exists in that page, and so forth)
- `-p` - Downloads everything needed for the page to be properly viewed
- `-k` - Converts the links in the documents to make them suitable for local viewing
- `-np` - Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively (i.e. don't go back)
- `-w 1` - Waits 1 second between every retrieval. This is useful for not overloading the server with requests, which can cause 404 errors and other stuff.

The argument usage is taken form [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). I haven't run this so I can't say for sure it will crawl appropriately, but with some adjustments it would do the trick.